# Microsoft.Graph.Group missing resourceProvisioningOptions atrribute

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to identify Teams by displayname using the .NET SDK. I'm not using the beta API on purpose as I'm creating a production application. In order to identify a group that is a Team i'm wanting to use the resourceProvisioningOptions as that contains a value of "Team".

In postman I can do this simply via

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'My Team')
```

In the returned attributes I see

```
"resourceProvisioningOptions": [
   "Team"
]
```

The C# I'm using to do the same thing is

```
var request = await graphClient.Groups
    .Request()
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .Filter("startswith(displayName,'My Team')")
    .Select("id,displayName,description,resourceProvisoiningOptions")
    .GetAsync();
```

Then (for testing sake)

```
foreach (var item in request) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.id);
    Console.WriteLine(item.resourceProvisioningOptions);
}
```

However the Microsoft.Graph.Group Type doesn't appear to have the resourceProvisioningOptions property. So i'm wondering how I could correctly identify Team Groups.

I know with the Beta API i can filter our non Team Groups using resouceProvisioningOptions/Any(etc) but as I mentioned I'm not going to use that.

This is my first post and thanks in advance of any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you said even I am also unable to see `resourceProvisioningOptions` when I try to query list of Group. After some research I found, there are some properties that can be found in the AdditionalData property while debugging and you can see the `resourceProvisioningOptions` in that property.

You can enumerate that data using the below code.

```
IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage m = await GraphHelper.getGroups();
foreach (var data in m)
{
        Console.WriteLine(data.AdditionalData["resourceProvisioningOptions"] + " " + data.displayName);
}
```

Each Group has AdditionalData and use it to get your missing properties.

Comment: Thanks Shiva! That looks like it does the job.